# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Set (react.js Only in safari this error is coming)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Set (react.js Only in safari this error is coming) on all other browsers its working perfect but in safari throwing this error showing error in main.js which was build by react when i run this command
(npm run build)

Comment: It seems that you are defining a variable with name Set.
Please do not use that kind of names -- they may be used by some browser or system. Add some prefix or suffix to your variable name.

Answer (score 10):

You should consider including a global polyfill in your bundled application, such as [core-js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js) or [babel-polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/).

Run `npm install core-js` or `yarn add core-js` and import your specific required features, like so:

```
  import 'core-js/es6/map';
  import 'core-js/es6/set';
  import 'core-js/fn/array/find';
  import 'core-js/fn/array/includes';
  import 'core-js/fn/number/is-nan';

  import React from 'react';
  import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

  ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

More info: https://reactjs.org/docs/javascript-environment-requirements.html

Answer (score 1):

You can add `import "core-js/fn/set";` into your pollyfill.js file, in order to support old browsers.

Note: Please install "core-js" package incase you don't have.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) helps to improve the quality of your response. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.